# Set database schema name without setting table name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, database-schema

I want to set database schema name for a table, but the only way do it is using method `ToTable`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().ToTable("MyTable", schemaName);
```

However I don't want to set table name explicitly, I need something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().ToSchema(schemaName);
```

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: could you elaborate on the motivation ? It is not unclear how the entity will be usable without a table name

Comment: I wrote 'explicitly',implicitly tablename will be set.

Comment: Custom conventions set aside, will it not be the same as ToTable(typeof(MyEntity).Name, schemaName) ?

Comment: @jbl No, the table name won't necessarily match the type name (e.g. pluralisations)

Answer (score -1):

Using this extension method:

```
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
public static class ModelConfigurationHelper
{
    public static EntityTypeConfiguration<T> ToSchema<T>(this EntityTypeConfiguration<T> config, string schema)
    {
        return config.ToTable(typeof(T).Name, schema);
    }
}
```

you can do:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().ToSchema("someSchema);
}
```